# Emulate these FTP settings with FTP?

Tags: php, ftp

I am using ftp_connect and the various other FTP functions to provide an automated transfer service.

Everything was working well until someone sent me these transfer specifications.

FTP port type: FTPES - FTP over explicit TLS/SSL(FTPS (SSL/TLS))

Does anyone know what this means? Does anyone know if this can be achieved with the ftp PHP functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [`ftp_ssl_connect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php). For more information about FTPES, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS#Explicit.